# Can you determine the output format of an ffmpeg command?

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there an "easy" way to know the output format from a part of the ffmpeg "processing chain"? What I mean is: if I use, for example, a video decoder of h264_cuvid, it can have troubles being the input to a filter like yadif (vs. yadif_cuda).

Just trying to understand the pieces in the chain better, so I know determine what parts play together better.

Answer (score 1):

No, the "processing chain" consists of various stages, e.g. transport protocol negotiation, filtering, encoding, to name a random few. For each stage, there are multiple choices, sometimes numbering in the dozens, for which module carries out the task. And all choices aren't determined based on the content of the input, but can also be the byproduct of a choice the user makes, like your manual choice of decoder, or a choice of a filter, which only accepts certain pixel formats. So, there isn't an easy way for a user, with a bird's eye view, to predict conflicts. The user has to dive into the details.

Comment: OK, that makes sense - thanks! But how to "dive into the details"? That's what I'm wanting to do, just not sure how to get the needed info.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the "file" command?

```
$ file something.avi 
something.avi: RIFF (little-endian) data, AVI, 720 x 528, 23.98 fps, video: XviD, audio: MPEG-1 Layer 3 (stereo, 48000 Hz)
```

If "file" doesn't tell you enough, or if you're one of those annoying people like me who like to know all the details, there's a command that comes with ffmpeg called "ffprobe":

```
$ ffprobe something.avi
ffprobe version 4.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/local --enable-swscale --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-librsvg --enable-libtheora --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libmodplug --enable-libvpx --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-lzma --enable-gnutls --enable-fontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --disable-libjack --disable-libopencore-amrnb --disable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-indev=jack --enable-opencl --disable-outdev=xv --enable-audiotoolbox --enable-videotoolbox --enable-sdl2 --disable-securetransport --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --cc=/usr/bin/cc --arch=x86_64 --enable-x86asm --enable-libx265 --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, avi, from 'something.avi':
  Duration: 01:30:05.91, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 760 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Advanced Simple Profile) (XVID / 0x44495658), yuv420p, 720x528 [SAR 1:1 DAR 15:11], 665 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 23.98 tbn, 23.98 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 81 kb/s
```